# .change() not firing after form been filled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having serious headache with this code, the function .change(validate); it's not firing, after the form has been filled!
Any suggestions???

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    validate();
    $('#SUEmail', '#SUName', '#SUPassword','#SUConfPassword').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#SUEmail').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('#SUName').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#SUPassword').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('#SUConfPassword').val().length    >   0) {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to write function outside of onDeviceReady and give a commom-class to all them and use  $('.commom-class').on("change",function(){
validate();
});
              });

Comment: Use `$('#SUEmail, #SUName, #SUPassword,#SUConfPassword').change(validate);`

Comment: @AkshayTilekar: The OP's function is already outside the `ready` handler, and that's actually a bad thing, not a good thing. It works either way, but putting it outside makes it a global.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah,thats right

Answer (score 0):

`$('#SUEmail', '#SUName', '#SUPassword','#SUConfPassword')` isn't valid, see [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery). You're passing a series of individual strings into the function.

You probably wanted a single string using a [CSS group](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping):

```
$('#SUEmail, #SUName, #SUPassword, #SUConfPassword').change(validate);
```

...but note that `change` doesn't fire until focus *leaves* an element, so you might consider the `input` event instead.

I'd also move your `validate` function *into* the `ready` handler so it's not a global. Globals are a Bad Thing™. The global namespace is *really* crowded. Adding to it when you can avoid adding to it isn't a good idea.

Example with the CSS group, using `input` as well as `change`, and moving `validate`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  validate();
  $('#SUEmail, #SUName, #SUPassword, #SUConfPassword').on("input change", validate);

  function validate() {
    if ($('#SUEmail').val().length > 0 &&
      $('#SUName').val().length > 0 &&
      $('#SUPassword').val().length > 0 &&
      $('#SUConfPassword').val().length > 0) {
      $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;/*For demo purposes*/">
  <input id="SUEmail" type="text">
  <input id="SUName" type="text">
  <input id="SUPassword" type="password">
  <input id="SUConfPassword" type="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```